# How to join two tables to get the following result?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'd like to join two tables.

**TABLE_A**

```
GROUP0     GROUP1     SUM_A
---------------------------
01           A         100         
01           B         200
04           D         700
```

**TABLE_B**

```
GROUP0      GROUP1     SUM_B
---------------------------
01                     300
01           A         350
02           B         400
03           C         500
```

How to join the tables to get the following result?

```
GROUP0     GROUP1          SUM_A           SUM_B
------------------------------------------------
01                             0            300
01          A                100            350
01          B                200              0
02          B                  0            400
03          C                  0            500
04          D                700              0
```

Comment: What happened to 01/B in the first table?

Comment: sorry sir, i think i have some mistakes, it is correct now.

Comment: I have sth problem.
if the column Value is NULL, it cannot match the column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want everything in the second table and then matching rows or new `group0` in the first table.

I think this is the `join` logic:

```
select coalesce(t1.group0, t2.group0) as group0, 
       coalesce(t1.group1, t2.group1) as group1,
       t1.sum_a, t2.sum_b
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.group0 = t2.group0 
where (t2.group0 is not null and (t1.group1 = t2.group1 or t1.group0 is null)) or
      t2.group0 is null;
```

This logic is easier with `union all`:

```
select t2.group0, t2.group1, t1.sum_a, t2.sum_b
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.group0 = t1.group0 and t2.group1 = t1.group1
union all
select t1.group1, t1.group1, t1.suma, 0
from table1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.group0 = t1.group0);
```

EDIT:

The modified question is quite different from the original.  That is a simple `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.group0, t2.group0) as group0, 
       coalesce(t1.group1, t2.group1) as group1,
       coalesce(t1.sum_a, 0) as sum_a, coalesce(t2.sum_b, 0) as sum_b
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.group0 = t2.group0  and t1.group1 = t2.group1;
```

Comment: I want everything in the second table, 
1. Match  group0 and group1
2. if match -> add the value in that row,
3. if not match -> add a new row